# graphic error on console

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, graphics, console

I have Linux on an embedded system. There is no graphic system, but I still have graphic errors.
For example, if I type:
ifconfig eth2 hw ether 00:0e:8c:d0:59:d2
I see:
ifconfig eth2 hw etherhw0:0e:8c:d0:59:c:d
If I type Enter, it accepts the command I typed, so it's just a matter of displaying.
Everything is fine, when I log in via SSH.

It seems like the characters from 7 spaces left are mirrored, if I type the same it is always the same thing displayed, but note that if I type something else like "012345678901234567989" exactly that is displayed.

Also the problem is not specific to ifconfig, e.g. it also happens to "tail -f /var/log/sysl", which is shown as "tailf -f /var/log/sysl o", but the additional "o" disappears, when i continue typing.

If i type "tail -f /var/log/messages" everything is ok

It feels like this sort of thing only happens to valid commands and not to random stuff I type. It is not related to commands being used before, but I still suspect some kind of auto-completion problem

Anyone any ideas, what could be the cause or where to look at?

Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3100 Chipset Memory I/O Controller Hub
00:00.1 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation 3100 DRAM Controller Error Reporting Registers
00:01.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 3100 Chipset Enhanced DMA Controller
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 3100 Chipset PCI Express Port A
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 3100 Chipset PCI Express Port A1
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset EHCI USB2 Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c9)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset SATA IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
03:01.0 Network controller: Siemens Nixdorf AG Device 4003 (rev 02)
03:01.1 Unassigned class [ff00]: Siemens Nixdorf AG Device 4003 (rev 02)
03:02.0 Ethernet controller: Siemens Nixdorf AG Device 4047 (rev 01)
03:03.0 Ethernet controller: National Semiconductor Corporation DP83815 (MacPhyter) Ethernet Controller
03:04.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Siemens Nixdorf AG Device 4057 (rev 01)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2000(A)/XIO2200(A) PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 44)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2000(A)/XIO2200(A) PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge (rev 03)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Motion, Inc. SM720 Lynx3DM (rev c1)
07:01.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB (rev 43)
07:01.1 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB (rev 43)
07:01.2 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB 2.0 (rev 04)
```

The whole thing is running on an Intel Core 2 Duo U2500
I'm using bash, but sh is showing the same behaviour

Comment: I can’t help except to say that this doesn’t sound like a [tag:graphics-card] issue to me.  What happens if you type `echo "ifconfig eth2 hw ether 00:0e:8c:d0:59:d2"`?  Can you narrow down the symptoms?  For example, based on your example, I guess it’s not just not displaying the character ‘`2`’.  But does it always drop the 13th and 31st characters?

Comment: ok my posted example was more random and not the exact thing, i going to correct it and explain a bit more

Comment: Auto-complete, huh?  Interesting idea.  If you want us to think about that, I suggest that you tell us what shell you’re running (`bash`, `csh`, `ksh`, etc.).  Do you have any documentation on how auto-complete works on your system?  (Can you figure out whether it is turned on, and, if so, how to turn it off?)  What is your `TERM` environment variable set to (type `echo "$TERM"` and `echo "$term"`) on the console and when logged in through `ssh`?  Can you do command-line editing (e.g., type `ifcofig←←←n→→→`)?  Can you run `vi`?

Comment: I'm running bash, sh is showing the same behaviour, no other shells installed.
TERM="linux"
term=" "
vi is working fine
command line editing works fine
auto-completion is turned on like ifco[TAB] = ifconfig

on ssh $TERM = "xterm", that's the only difference